# Concise adjective for 'supposed-to-be'

Tags: single-word-requests, concision

I'm creating a clone of a popular app (let's call it Appo), and with time, I foresee the clone looking less like the original.

The best description I could come up with for this project is:

> A supposed-to-be Appo clone

I don't like it and I believe there must be a one-word adjective that can replace 'supposed-to-be'.

Comment: Uh… no. That has pretty-much nothing to do with English, of any kind.

Comment: I almost think I wish I knew what you meant by *a Google keep clone repository on Github* or by *as time progresses, it will deviate considerably from what Google Keep currently looks and behaves like.*

When you want to capture your thoughts above concisely and enter into the optional description field, could you re-phrase that so it meant something useful in English, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds as if you are creating a **"purported"** Google Keep clone.

**Purport**

> Etymology:  < Anglo-Norman and Middle French purporter (of a text)
>   **to have as its import, to signify, to mean,** to state or show (a fact) (all first half of the 14th cent. or earlier in Anglo-Norman;
>   end of the 13th cent. or earlier in Anglo-Norman in sense ‘(of a word)
>   to mean, signify’; late 12th cent. in Old French as porporter  in
>   sense ‘to involve (as an obligation)’) < post-classical Latin
>   proportare  to carry or bear forth (8th cent. in past participle
>   proportatus ), to stretch, extend (from 12th cent. in British sources;
>   from 13th cent. in continental sources; also as porportare ), to have
>   as its import (from c1200 in British sources; also as porportare ) <
>   classical Latin pro- pro- prefix1  + portāre port v.2, perhaps as a
>   remodelling of classical Latin praeportāre  to carry in front, in
>   post-classical Latin also to stretch, extend (in an undated source in
>   Du Cange) < prae- pre- prefix  + portāre . Compare proport v. In sense
>   2  (which is apparently not paralleled in either Latin or French)
>   after purport n.; compare purpose v.

OED.